# Meaning of "ausrichten"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I've encountered this word twice in one of the *Dragon Ball* mangas, and none of the [translations in the dictionary](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=ausrichten&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on&pos=0) seem to fit. First one, Vegeta stares powerless as Freezers beats Son Gohan, and says

> Son Gohan ist mir schnuppe, aber was kann ich gegen Frezeers gewaltige
>   Kraft **ausrichten**?

I would just translate it as "do", but I would expect it to appear in the dictionary at least as *ugs*. A few pages later, as Kuririn is about to try and run away from Freezer, he says

> **Ausrichten** kann ich nichts. Nur weg laufen!!!

Here, "do" might make sense, but less than in the previous example.

So what does *ausrichten* mean in these examples?

Comment: You need to use a proper dictionary, and not one of these amateur-made open-source error-riddled word lists on the internet. Look here, meaning 2 is the one you want: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ausrichten

Comment: I disagree; I think OP’s usage of Leo was exemplary.

Comment: @Jan I'm not sure I'm seeing the same version of Leo that you see, because in my version of the linked page the meaning "do, achieve, ..." is not even present. How is using a dictionary that does not provide all meanings exemplary?

Comment: @what OP’s *way* of using Leo was exemplary. enter the word, go through the list, consider which words may transport the intended meaning better or worse. As I don’t think any dictionary will ever be able to provide all possible translations for all words, you’re bound to run into ‘nothing fits’ at some point or another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost every word in almost every language has more than one meaning. »Ausrichten« is just one of those multi-meaning-words:

The separable verb »ausrichten« can mean:

**1. to adjust**

> Ich werde die Bauteile **ausrichten**.
> I will **adjust** the components.
>
> Benutzen Sie das Rändelrad C um die Bauteile F und G parallel zueinander **aus**zu**richten**.
> Use knurl C to **adjust** the components F and G parallel to each other.

**2. to align**

> Ich werde den Text **ausrichten**.
> I will adjust the text.
>
> **Richten** Sie den Text entlang des rechten Randes **aus**.
> **Align** the text along the right border.

**3. to orient**

> Ich werde das Gebäude nach Osten **ausrichten**.
> I will **orient** the building to the east.
>
> Fast alle Kirchen sind nach Osten **aus**ge**richtet**.
> Almost all churches are **oriented** to the east.

**4. to hold (hold a party)**

> Ich werde eine Feier ausrichten.
> I will hold a party.
>
> Sie können Ihre Feier hier, in unserem großen Saal, **ausrichten**.
> You can **hold** your party here, in our great hall.

**5. to organize**

> Ich werde eine Messe **ausrichten**.
> I will **organize** a trade fair.
>
> Um die Garten-Messe **aus**zu**richten** brauchen wir viel Platz.
> We need much space to **organize** the gardening trade fair.

**6. to tell**

> Ich werde es ihm **ausrichten**.
> I will **tell** him.
>
> **Richte** deinem Freund **aus**, er soll zur Hölle fahren.
> **Tell** your friend to go to hell.

**7. to do** (in the sense of »achieve«)

> Ich kann etwas **ausrichten**.
> I can **do** something.
> I can **achieve** something.
>
> Gegen den neuen Virus kann dieses Medikament nichts **ausrichten**.
> This medicine can't **do** anything against against this new virus.
> This medicine can't **achieve** anything against against this new virus.

(Maybe there are even more meanings)

---

In both of your sentences is »ausrichten« used in the menaing listed here as #7: »to do/achive something«, and so I would translate your sentences this way:

> Son Gohan ist mir schnuppe, aber was kann ich gegen Frezeers gewaltige Kraft **ausrichten**?
> I don't mind about Son Gohon. But what can I **do/achieve** against Freezers enormous power?
>
> **Ausrichten** kann ich nichts. Nur weg laufen!
> I can't **do/achieve** anything. Just run away!

Answer (score 4):

It has, as usual, various meanings. For the meaning you are looking for I'd simply suggest *achieve*.

Comment: And on top of that, it is in a similar register.

Answer (score 3):

*ausrichten* is a verb with a whole bunch of possible meanings, driven by context and/or the used preposition.

*ausrichten gegen* in the context of your examples could be translated as

- There's nothing I can do about Frezeer
- I have nothing to counter[act] him with
- I have no means against him

(Although I don't have the slightest idea what Mr. Frezeer is - But I probably don't want to know...)

Answer (score -3):

The fixed phrase is *etwas ausrichten gegen*. Meaning literally **to aim against** some attacker.

When you cannot aim something useful against an attacker, your best bet is to flee.

Comment: Disagree - *etwas ausrichten auf* is **aiming** (e.g. *die Kanone auf das Ziel ausrichten*)  *etwas ausrichten gegen* is not.

Comment: How do you think about *entgegnen* then?

Comment: nah. "etwas tun gegen"